# selecting multiple columns but group by only one in postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a simple table in postgres:

```
remoteaddr        count
142.4.218.156     592
158.69.26.144     613
167.114.209.28    618
```

Which I pulled using the following:

```
select remoteaddr,
count (remoteaddr)
from domain_visitors
group by remoteaddr
having count (remoteaddr) > 500
```

How do I select additional columns and still only group by `remoteaddr`?

Comment: Please give your table full structure

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:** You could use the [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) function to concatenate the additional column values into a grouped list:

```
SELECT 
   remoteaddr, 
   array_agg(DISTINCT username) AS unique_users, 
   array_agg(username) AS repeated_users, 
   count(remoteaddr) as remote_count
FROM domain_visitors
GROUP BY remoteaddr;
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/37a37/12). This query would return something like the below:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|   remoteaddr   |          unique_users           |                                           repeated_users                                            | remote_count |
+----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  142.4.218.156 | anotheruser,user9688766,vistor1 | user9688766,anotheruser,vistor1,vistor1,vistor1,vistor1,vistor1,anotheruser,anotheruser,anotheruser |           10 |
|  158.69.26.144 | anotheruser,user9688766         | anotheruser,user9688766,user9688766,user9688766,user9688766                                         |            5 |
| 167.114.209.28 | vistor1                         | vistor1                                                                                             |            1 |
+----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

**Option 2:** You could put your first query in a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) (aka a "WITH" clause), and join it against the original table, like this:

```
WITH grouped_addr AS (
  SELECT remoteaddr, count(remoteaddr) AS remote_count
  FROM domain_visitors
  GROUP BY remoteaddr
)

SELECT ga.remoteaddr, dv.username, ga.remote_count
FROM grouped_addr ga
INNER JOIN domain_visitors dv
ON ga.remoteaddr = dv.remoteaddr
WHERE remote_count > 500;
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/37a37/4).

Bear in mind that this will return repeated results for any additional columns (in this example, `username`). This is not *usually* what you want. Note each of the SELECT examples in the Fiddles and see which best suits your purpose.